# How to add timestamp in filename while exporting MatTable components?

Tags: html, angular, npm, angular-material, interpolation

I am using `mat-table-exporter` npm module to export mat table components.

I am able to export it correctly with `test` as the name of the exported file.

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('csv', {fileName:'test',
   Props: {Author: 'myName'}})">
   Export
</button>
```

I also want to add timestamp in the name of the exported file for which I am modifying `fileName`
to `test-{new Date()}` as below:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('csv', {fileName:'test-{new Date()}',
   Props: {Author: 'myName'}})">
   Export
</button>
```

The above code is throwing compile time errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some specific reason why this export function can't be inside the `.ts` file of the component? It's way easier to debug then and it offer better configuration options.

```
exportTable(): void {
  this.exporter.exportTable('csv', {
    filename: `test-${new Date().toISOString()}`,
    Props: { 
      Author: 'myName'
    }
  })
}
```

And then in template just call it.

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="exportTable()">Export</button>
```

Comment: this is throwing an error `TS2552: Cannot find name 'exporter'. `

Comment: isn't that the issue then? I can't tell how is the `exporter` provided, in my code `this.exporter` was just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this form; in the file .ts put this

```
import { formatDate} from '@angular/common';
@Component({
    // ...
})
export class AppComponent  {
datenow = new Date();
formatted: string;
constructor() {
      this.nowFormatted = formatDate(this.datenow, 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'en-US');
   }
}
```

and in the HTML
put this

```
                    <button style="float: right;"  (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'Applications_'+formatted})">
                    <img src="../../../assets/iconos/excel.png" alt="" />
                    </button>
```

the formatted variable in ts is now formated with the currentDate.

I hope I've helped